# How can I use a 3x3 matrix within a 4x4 matrix representation?

Tags: xna, matrix

In XNA there is only one Matrix class which is actually 4x4 matrix. How to use it to represent a 3x3 matrix?

I am trying to represent the inertia tensor of a body which is a 3x3 matrix, so I have data for only a 3x3 matrix. How can I store that in a 4x4 matrix and still have operations on it be valid?

Comment: Why not quickly roll your own Matrix3 class?  This sounds like data that has nothing to do with XNA and therefore it makes little sense to use XNA classes for it.

Comment: i want to be able to transform a Matrix3 by a Matrix4 (this is very important to me)

Comment: I see, Nicol's answer is what you need in that case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put zeros in the last column and row, except for the lower-left value which should be 1. Like this:

```
V  V  V  0
V  V  V  0
V  V  V  0
0  0  0  1
```

Where `V` are the actual values you use.

Comment: XNA operations still valid in this state ?

Comment: @MhdSyrwan: Unless XNA's matrix math code is completely broken, yes. Matrix math is matrix math; a matrix of all zeros is still a matrix.

Comment: Really he is asking you to make an identity matrix then copy your matrix 3x3.

Comment: note : XNA Matrix is stored as a row vector matrix (each vector is a row ) so if our Matrix3x3 is column vector , we should transpose it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old post, but it lists first in google search, and the accepted answer is incorrect. Correct answer is:

```
V V 0 V
V V 0 V
0 0 1 0
V V 0 v
```

PS In context of the question my answer is not correct. Sorry for that. I had to read question more carefully and clarify that this solution is correct when using 3x3 matrix for 2d homogeneous vector (x,y,w) and 4x4 for 3d homogeneous vector (x,y,z,w).

Comment: Umm, could you clarify? Atleast 12 people have found the existing answer correct or helpful.

Comment: Works either way, I would say Nicol's alternative is much clearer...

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. Though the method proposed here works, too, it’s more complex to set up and offers no benefit over the accepted answer. If you stumbled upon this question through a Google search and found out it didn’t solve your problem, it’s more likely that you didn’t actually have the same problem.

Comment: What he wrote here is packing a 3x3 matrix so that it can translate naturally in XNA. This 4x4 packing of a 3x3 matrix is to 2D space as the normal 4x4 matrix is to 3D space. OP however talked about an inertia tensor that is 3x3, so we can safely assume 3D space, in which case Nicolas answer is correct.